# Is there any class in c++ for representing time in milliseconds?

Tags: c++

Is there any class in c++ for representing time in milliseconds ?
I need to hold time and compare values, set time from device. Do I need to write my own or there is already ?  I looked at `<ctime>` and `time_t` but it can holds only seconds.

Comment: I don't know if it is an option, but [Boost DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/date_time.html) does this (and much more) very well.

Comment: look at std::chrono namespace.

Answer (score 5):

Well, C++11's [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) has a concept of [time duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), one of which is milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply dealing with millisecond time durations, then an integer type will be fine; perhaps using `typedef` to give it a friendly name.

POSIX does this with `time_t` (representing seconds) and `clock_t` (representing microseconds); standard C also specifies these types, but doesn't specify which units they use.

If you want to mix units, then `std::chrono`, or `boost::chrono` if you can't use C++11, have some nice types such as `duration` that wrap up integer values and automatically change scale as appropriate; so you can write things like `duration d = seconds(4) + milliseconds(123)`.

Comment: There's also [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/chrono.html).

Comment: @Xeo: So there is. That looks like a better option than `posix_time`.